# With a node.js powered server on EC2, how can I decrease the TCP connection time?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, node.js

While profiling my application I've noticed that in the Firebug Net panel, the "Connecting" time—that is the time waiting for a TCP connection—is consistently around 70–100ms. See image below:

[image: firebug net panel tcp connecting time]

Of course in the grand scheme of things, 100ms is not long, but I have seen other services that respond with 0ms Connect time. So if other servers can, I should be able to as well.

Any thoughts on how I might even beging to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from an Web Server perspective, and having used firebug a little bit.

I've seen the 0ms you speak of before, however I also bare that more to do with something called KeepAlives (in Apache and others). The idea being you make an initial request to a web server and if keep alive is allowed and turned on the connection after the web server has served that request isn't closed immediately, it stays alive for a set amount of time until reaching the timeout set within KeepAlive, this means that other elements on a web page can be requested to the same webserver and domain with the connection still established, thus saving the hold rig morale of the client having to re-connect again.

It has ups and downs, while its good as it improves speed ever so slightly, it can have an effect on a very busy application that so many requests are coming into the app and are waiting to timeout that you could eventually exhaust the number of connections.

This is all in a web server context but I don't see why the same wouldn't be possible for a node app. However i'd be surprised if your able to see 0ms connection time for a connection that isn't already opened and established, there's a few packets that have to go back and forth with SYN, SYN-ACKs and ACK for TCP connections, all that over remote servers is going to take more than 0ms.

I'm sure someone here has better idea on the node side but this i'm sure is still of use and relevant.

Cheers,
M